# Color of input value after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

when I enter a correct or incorrect form the color changes accordingly and when i remove it, it changes accordingly again however when i reenter or remove the input value the third time the color ceases to change as if the code is stuck and no longer is able

this is my url
http://codepen.io/epmiles/pen/ewEjn?editors=100

Comment: Its good that you have included codepen but always add your code at SO.

Comment: I think people prefer [jsfiddles](http://jsfiddle.net), though. The layout is better and they're easier to set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are not removing the already added classes(`failure`, `success`) from the input fields. So once a field is marked as valid(`success`), then if you make it invalid both the classes(`failure`, `success`) as assigned to it. Then since the `success` class is defined after `failure` it will get precedence.

So add the below before the field validation starts

```
name.add(pass).add(verify).add(email).removeClass('failure success');
```

Demo: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/arunpjohny/pen/rFgvD?editors=011)